Why doesn't the error stream from a runspace created with $Host appear in the console?
Consider the following PowerShell which writes to each of the (non-output) streams in the current runspace, then does the same in another runspace created with $Host:
$sb = {
    $DebugPreference = 'Continue'
    $InformationPreference = 'Continue'
    Write-Debug 'some debug'
    Write-Information 'some information'
    Write-Verbose 'some verbose' -Verbose
    Write-Warning 'some warning'
    Write-Error 'some error'
}

. $sb

'----'

$rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace($Host)
$rs.Open()
[powershell]::Create($rs).
    AddScript($sb).
    Invoke() | Out-Null

Running this in the PowerShell console outputs
VERBOSE: some verbose
WARNING: some warning
Write-Error: C:\test.ps1:13
Line |
  13 |  . $sb
     |  ~~~~~
     | some error
----
DEBUG: some debug
some information
VERBOSE: some verbose
WARNING: some warning

Why is the error written in the runspace missing from the output?

For future readers wondering how the answer to this question answers this question: Like for Start-ThreadJob -StreamingHost $Host the above runspace code directs everything except the "success" and error streams to $Host.  ThreadJobs reveal those remaining streams via Receive-Job.  There isn't a corresponding command for the above construction.  Instead those same streams are available on PowerShell.Streams.
